# Frame rate of video Python

Tags: python-2.7, video, time, frame-rate

Code:

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import sys
    import webcolors
    import time

    cam=cv2.VideoCapture('video2.avi')
    _, fo = cam.read()
    framei = cv2.cvtColor(fo, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    bg_avg = np.float32(framei)
    video_width = int(cam.get(3))
    video_height = int(cam.get(4))
    fr = int(cam.get(5))
    print("frame rate of stored video:::",fr)

    while(cam.isOpened): 
           f,img=cam.read()
           start_fps=time.time()
           .
           .
           .
           k = cv2.waitKey(20)
           if(k == 27):
               break
         endtime_fps=time.time()
         diff_fps=endtime_fps-start_fps
         print("Frame rate::",1/diff_fps)
```

With every iteration, this prints a different frame rate like: 31.249936670193268, 76.92300920661702,  142.85290010558222, 166.67212398172063, 200.00495922941204, 38.46150460330851... etc with some values being repeated a few times. Now the value of frame rate for the stored video is 25. So what is the actual frame rate at which it is being read?

Comment: The question assumes that the processes of accessing, reading and showing frames is consistent with the frame rate, which almost **never** is. In standard video playback, data is *requested* when required, *read* as soon as available, and "played" when possible: a frame could be *requested* much before than it will be actually be shown (because the player tries to *buffer* frames, for instance while streaming from net), shown much later than it should (because the CPU/GPU couldn't process it in time), or even *skipped* in case displaying would be delayed too much than the expected time.

Comment: If every frame is being processed, then the result is that each frame will be processed when: 1. it will be available; 2. when the CPU (and the OS) allows it. That is not the actual frame rate, it is the rate at which the computer is able to access the frame and eventually show it, which is a completely different aspect. Consider it like a car: the manufacturer says it can go up to 100mph, but if you put a 10t stone on its trunk, it will never reach that speed, and you cannot assume its maximum speed on "real world" tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain, but I think this might come down to your timing method. I don't think Python's `time.time()` method guarantees enough precision to provide the real-time profiling information you desire.

Comment: Even if it is not precise, should I be getting values atleast in the same range? How do I determine at what frame rate the video is being read?

Comment: A lot of this surely comes down to the vagaries of running on a non realtime system and the unpredictability of when your process gets scheduled to run after yielding the CPU to block on input.

Comment: So if I want to process the stored video at a certain frame rate, how do I do that?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your goal. Are you trying to capture frames, process them, and then display them back to the user on a real-time deadline? If you just want to, e.g., process the captured frames and store them to disc, then these timings are less interesting. In general, you can trust that the hardware is capturing the frames at a steady 25 frames/sec. The OS/language interpreter might introduce a bit of delay when delivering them to your program.

Answer (score 18):

You can get FPS(Frames Per Second) using the code below:

```
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture('video2.avi')
fps = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
```