# How to get video's data with python

Tags: python, image, computer-vision, video-processing

I need to retrive from a video all the information about it such as - frame rate, size, bits, length... and also all the frame's data (the pixels as 2D numpy array for example). Do you have a function in python that you can load a video, and then retrive from it all it's data? Thank's a lot!
I know there is such a function in matlab and I'm looking for a way of doing this on python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll benefit from the OpenCV library. You can install it several ways including [pip](pip install opencv-python) or [conda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv). Here's a few previous SO threads discussing your question.

- [Looping through frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36521957/9870343): the numpy array you're looking for is the `frame` variable immediately underneath the `while` statement
- [Retrieving frame rate and video duration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52032374/9870343)
- [Retrieving frame rate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50544345/9870343)